# What does only defined up to a constant mean?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This was an answer to the question: show that the problem is not well defined.

The variational formulation of a problem is given by
$$u\in V=L^2(0,1) \text{ such that } \int_0^1 u'v' = \int_0^1 fv \text{ } \forall v\in V$$
Now if we plug in $v= C$ for which holds that $v\in L^2(0,1)$ we get that $f$ should satisfy $\int_0^1 f C = \int_0^1 u' 0 \implies \int_0^1 f = 0$. This would mean that the solution is only defined up to a constant.

I follow this explanation until the last sentence. Could somebody elaborate on that?

Comment: I understand from this argument that $f$ must have vanishing integral in order for the problem to have any solution. If this is the case, then constants are solutions and so, if $u$ is a solution, so is $u+C$ for any constant $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is pre-given, and we want $u \in V$ such that

$$\forall v \in V: \int_0^1 u'v' = \int_0^1 fv$$

then indeed taking $v = C$ we get the necessary condition that $\int_0^1 f = 0$.

Also, if $u$ is a solution, then so is $u + C$ for any constant $C$, as $(u+C)' = u'$ for all $C$ and $u$ only appears in the derivative. And two continuously differentiable functions on $(0,1)$ with the same derivative differ by a constant. 
So presumably the latter is meant.